# Switch material during animation

Tags: animation, materials

I have a scene with a bunch of bouncing balloons and I need to switch materials during animation. The transition doesn't have to be smooth. Just adjusting and keyframing one material won't do, since all the balloons have the same default material, so if I change the material, it affects all the balloons.
Here are some of the ways I could think of for solving this, but none of them seems very effective...
Option one is to make a copy of the material for every animated object and animate that, but that would leave me with way too many unnecesary materials (one for each balloon that changes color)
Option two is to have another balloon with the other material and have them switch places instead of switching the material.
Are there any better ways of going about this?

Comment: You can't change material with animation, but you can animate the material's parameters for example its color in the shader editor.

Comment: Because of what FFeller points out, you can create a larger material that uses mix shader or mix rgb nodes across a number of "sub-materials", and then keyframe the mixing factors to cause transitions in look when desired.

Comment: I know I can do that, the problem is, that the material is assigned to multiple objects and only one of them is supposed to change. So the answer is, that there is no way to do it then.